# Flat base change preserves the property of being non-degenerate

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

We say a homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ of noetherian rings is *non-degenerate* if the induced map $f^*:{\rm Spec}(B) \rightarrow {\rm Spec}(A)$ maps ${\rm Ass}(B)$ into ${\rm Ass}(A)$.

> Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g:A \rightarrow C$ be homomorphisms of noetherian rings. Suppose
>
> 1. $B \otimes_{A}C$ is noetherian,
> 2. $f$ is flat,
> 3. $g$ is non-degenerate.
>
> Then $1_{B} \otimes g:B \rightarrow B \otimes_A C$ is also non-degenerate.

I was trying to say that $f^*({\rm Ass}(B \otimes C)) \subset {\rm Ass}(B)$, but still stuck.

Comment: @user26857: Since the title refers to base change, I would guess that the OP means the $A$-algebra map $B \cong B \otimes_A A \xrightarrow{B \otimes g} B \otimes_A C$, which does indeed send $b \mapsto b \otimes 1$

Comment: OP: The following proposition may be helpful: If $f : R \to S$ is a map of Noetherian rings, and $M$ is an $S$-module, then $f^*(\text{Ass}_S(M)) = \text{Ass}_R(M)$

Comment: For anyone interested, this question comes from a proposition on page 60 of Matsumura's commutative algebra textbook.